# Use Ethernet port for my Docker container but never outside

Tags: macos, network, ethernet, docker

I'm trying to get a setup ready, where I have a Mac Mini connected to two different ethernet connections.

It should look something like this:

- Port 01: routes directly to the Docker container.
- Port 02: used by the OS and everything else outside of the Docker
  container

Setting port01 for the container and port02 for the OS should work fine.

*But how do I make sure, that macOS is never going to switch to port01, even if port02 is unavailable?*

I guess I can't just turn it off since it's needed by the container, but maybe I can not allow any connections on that port that come from outside of the container?

Comment: What you are describing is a *firewall*.  pf comes with macOS by default.